# form that saves information entered into a data.txt file php none of them works

Tags: php, html, forms

i'am looking for form that has index.html and process.php
In index you enter Your Name: 
Your age: (but you dont enter it gives you option from 10 to 50) and you click submit 
and that information saves in data.txt file on /var/www/html not on client side.
I've tried hundred of them none of them works

Also please don't link other forms i've tried hundred of them on stack, on google, look they are all outdated?
I'am using Ubuntu 18.04 lts server, with apache2 installed and php, PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u6 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 18:50:20) ( NTS )
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Server built:   2019-10-13T15:43:54

Comment: Stack overflow is not where you ask how to do some task/activity. This is the forum where to ask when you get stuck doing something.

Comment: Sir, that is correct. I'am stuck on this and i can't get to work any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web server probably does not have write permission on */var/www/html*.

Try this very dangerous command that gives everyone write access:

```
chmod 777 /var/www/html
```

I will assume you are just testing so opening it up to the world should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks ! That works !, well is there any way to make it secure?

Comment: Yes. Don't write to /var/www/html.  You could create a sub-directory and write to that. But honestly you should avoid writing to the web root whenever possible. Standard convention is to write to a directory in /opt.